# Java: Matching up Lists inside nested Lists

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I have an interesting dilemma:

I've got a class, let's say it's called FileCabinet.

The FileCabinet stores a LinkedList of Files, called "filesInCabinet".

Inside each File, there is yet another LinkedList of Files, called "relatedFiles".

So it kind of looks something like this for example:

FileCabinet1

- File1

  - File3
- File2

  - File3
  - File4
- File3

  - File1
  - File2
- File4

  - File2

The problem i'm having, is the nested lists ("relatedFiles") contain **seperate instances** of the Files, so in reality it's more like:

FileCabinet1

- File1

  - File3_duplicate
- File2

  - File3_duplicate2
  - File4_duplicate
- File3

  - File1_duplicate
  - File2_duplicate
- File4

  - File2_duplicate2

With this, when I go to change a property of a File in one of the nested Lists, I want it to change the property of the real File too, but it only changes the duplicate's property.

Is there an efficient way I can 'match-up' the Files within the nested Lists to the non-nested List of Files? Each File also contains unique Strings, Integers and such, so it's easy to determine which File a duplicate is a clone of.

Comment: Why not build the list out of references instead of duplicates in the first place?

Comment: This is not clear, You say "I want to change the property of the real file". What do you mean by "real file"? Are these files java.io.File? What properties are you changing in the file instances that are not reflected in the "real file"? I think more information is needed here.

Comment: They're not java.io.File's. I called them that just because I needed to call them something, I even said it was just an example. They're just simple Java Classes.

Comment: Would be easier with some code. Why don't you keep track of the duplicate files in another collection, something like a `Map<YourFile, Set<YourFile>>` so that when you modify something you update them all, and changes gets reflected everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an quite fast way to do this, putting all files in a set and build the related files again. Like this:

```
Map<File, File> existingFiles = new Map<File, File>();
for (File f : filesInCabinet) {
   existingFiles.put(f, f);
}

for (File f : filesInCabinet) {
   List<File> relatedFiles = f.getRelatedFiles();
   for (int i = 0; i < relatedFiles.size(); i++) {
      File relatedFile = existingFiles.get(relatedFiles.get(i));
      relatedFiles.set(i, relatedFile);
   }
}
```

It works just putting files into a map and replacing the files on the related list with the one that is got from Map due the equals / hashcode implementation, so when you provide a related object you get the instance from the main list (filesInCabinet).

This means hashCode and equals needs to be implemented on File.

Comment: Thanks! Although that's a strange way to iterate through a List. Personally I would do for ( File f : relatedFiles)

Comment: This way was used just to have access to the index ;)